# "not only that but" versus "not only that, but"

Tags: commas

> He's right, not only that but he's the one who can save us.
>
> He's right. Not only that, but he's the one who can save us.

Do we really have to put a comma before but in both sentences? I am wondering, because in certain cases we don't have to put a comma following a comma.

For example:

> He's right, and because of that he's worth listening.

We don't put a comma after because of that, because of the and.

Answer (score 1):

Every time I see a question about punctuation, I remember that students do not know that punctuation is determined by style guides, which differ.

With that said, I would never punctuate as is shown the first example. As for the second example, the punctuation strikes me as something that most style guides would find perfectly acceptable. In terms of style, I'd prefer

> He's not only right, but also he's the only one who can save us.

And for the third example, I would punctuate it as

> He's right, and, because of that, he is worth listening to

to indicate the parenthetical nature of the phrase "because of that."

The best rule of thumb is that you need punctuation in writing wherever a pause would come in speech.